# Laravel Route Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a working solution within routes.php, but I understand that laravel can handle restful routes better. I've tried using their documentation to implement restful resource controllers, but had no luck.

This is what I have at the moment

```
Route::get('/invoices', 'InvoicesController@showInvoices');
Route::get('/invoices/data', 'InvoicesController@getInvoices');
```

Basically, the showInvoices returns the invoices view and getInvoices returns a JSON string for DataTables which is called from the invoices view.

So I want to be able to call /invoices to get the view and then call /invoices/data using JavaScript.

Any suggestions how to convert this to a resource controller or more suitable controller?

Comment: Are you want O/P in Json format, I mean RestApi.

Comment: did you rendered the invoices `view` before returning

Comment: Try again with resource controller, everything you can do with it https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers then if you want to extend resource simple use `Route::get('invoices/data', 'InvoiceController@method');` before defining resource controller in your route file.

Comment: Both the JSON and view are already programmed, it all works perfect. Just wondering how to change the above code to use a route controller.

Comment: What you want to change isn't really clear. Both your requests will be RESTful `get()` requests

Comment: Apologies. I do want to two RESTful get requests, but I just wondered if there was a cleaner way to write this as they are both in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was a cleaner way. Route controllers were supported up to Laravel 5.3. Then this functionality was removed in favor of explicit routes, which leave the routes files in disarray when you have lots of routes.

Fortunately, there is a class I wrote called AdvancedRoute, which serves as a drop in replacement.

In your case you can use it like this:

```
Route::get('/invoices', 'InvoicesController@showInvoices');
Route::get('/invoices/data', 'InvoicesController@getInvoices');
```

Becomes:

```
AdvancedRoute::controller('/invoices', 'InvoicesController');
```

Explicit routes are built automatically for you. Have in mind you have to follow a convention by prefixing the method names with the request method, which I personally find very clean and developer friendly:

```
InvoicesController@getInvoices => /invoices
InvoicesController@getInvoicesData => /invoices/data
```

Full information how to install and use find at the GitHub repo at:

https://github.com/lesichkovm/laravel-advanced-route

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "resource" route like so:

`Route::resource('/invoices', 'InvoicesController');`

Which will provide RESTful routes (GET, POST, PUT, etc...) for that particular `/invoices` route/resource. You can check this by executing `php artisan route:list`

You can learn more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

I hope this helped.

Cheers!